# Detect UIPageViewController begin swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` inside a `ViewController` which contains a `UICollectionView` to indicate which page is on, and on `didSelectItemAt` it sets the child VC to be shown.

I need to disable interactions on `UICollectionView` while the page view is being touched so there will be no interruptions with the way I handle page selection.

I have tried adding a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and using this method below:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    _delegate?.stopTouches()
}
```

I haven't found a way to do so up to this point.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate

It tells you when the gesture starts and when it ends.